# Does Drools 7.39.0 support jBoss EAP

Tags: drools

Since Drools 7.24.0, no .war file for EAP7 is shipped anymore. Any reason why? Can we use the Wildfly war file instead?

Comment: You can _try_ to use the Wildlfly war, but just like you cannot sub in wildlfly for the no-longer-shipped Tomcat war it will likely not work (and if it does work, any issues you find will possibly be because of this discrepancy.) Drools has stopped directly supporting these other systems since the release you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas. Just wondering, why support for jBoss EAP was dropped? Is it simply to keep EAP support for Red Hat Decision Manager, while Drools, being community edition, has support for Wildfly only.

Comment: That's something you'd have to ask the JBoss folks directly, though I'm sure whatever answer you get will be couched in some sort of political/marketing language so it's not obviously "we should support our paid products first and foremost". Yours is a logical enough theory that might well be true.